# How to locate the web element?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

```
<a class="top-menu-item float-start  p-2" href="/StudentPortal/Home/Login"> تسجيل دخول </a>
```

Im not able to locate the element mentioned above for automation purpose

I have tried the below  xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/header/div[1]/div/a[3]"));
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/header/div[1]/div/a[3]"));
```

Comment: Please add the html of the element you are trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following xpath -

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/StudentPortal/Home/Login')"))`

Comment: You shouldn't need `contains()` since that's the only string in the `href`.

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element you can use either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *partialLinkText*:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("تسجيل دخول"));
  ```
- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.top-menu-item.float-start.p-2[href='/StudentPortal/Home/Login']"));
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='top-menu-item float-start  p-2' and @href='/StudentPortal/Home/Login']"));
  ```

Comment: Your first locator won't work because you are missing the padding spaces on either side of the text. The rest are just messy because you are including EVERYTHING in the element as a locator which just makes them more likely to be brittle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below locators:

Xpath
CSS
ID